# How to move text list items to align with an image list item

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hi new to CSS here could anyone help me get the text to move down so it's aligned with my logo image? Also as an extension on that question does anyone know how I can make the text move across so the margins on either side match?
This is what it looks like now:
[image: Image of my header with text out of place]

Here is the html:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrap">
        <nav id="topnav"> <!-- This is the top nav bar-->
            <ul id="topnavlist">
                <li> <!-- Home logo-->
                    <div class="logo">  
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/TechNow Logo 0.2.jpg" alt="TechNow Logo" height="70" width="auto"></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                        <div class="navItems"><!-- Nav items-->
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="NavItem">UK News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="NavItem">Smartphones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="NavItem">Reviews</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    #header, #footer {
    background-color:#115279;
    float:left;
    padding:15px 0;
    min-width:100%;
}

.wrap {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
}

#topnavlist  li {
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#D9330F;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    display:inline;
    padding: 10px;
}

.navItems {
    height: 20%;
    display: inline;
    margin-top:30px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding: 50px;

}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you have `li` in a div with no parent `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, you can't have `div` inside `li`. Replace `div` with `li` and wrap their children(`li`s) in a `ul`.

To vertically center the `li`s, give `.navItems` a `height: 50px` same as the height of your logo and give it a `line-height: 50px`(`height`)

```css
#header,
#footer {
  background-color: #115279;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}
#topnavlist li {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #D9330F;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navItems {
  display: inline;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="wrap">
    <nav id="topnav">
      <!-- This is the top nav bar-->
      <ul id="topnavlist">
        <li>
          <!-- Home logo-->
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
              <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/000/fff" alt="TechNow Logo" height="70" width="auto">
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navItems">
          <!-- Nav items-->
          <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="NavItem">UK News</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="NavItem">Smartphones</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="NavItem">Reviews</a>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `div` element as a child to a `ul` element. As for aligning all of your elements. By default, the `img` and `a` elements are considered `inline` elements in css. You can use the `vertical-align` property on inline elements. So your markup could be a bit more simple like

```
<nav id="topnav">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="images/TechNow Logo 0.2.jpg" alt="TechNow Logo" height="70" width="auto"></a>
  <a href="#" class="NavItem">UK News</a>
  <a href="#" class="NavItem">Smartphones</a>
  <a href="#" class="NavItem">Reviews</a>
</nav>
```

and then the css

```
#topnav a {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Since I don't have the exact size of your image, this won't get you exactly what you're looking for, but it should get you on the right track. The main thing is to make sure you have valid HTML markup. This can cause many headaches and issues with your css if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your current HTML is invalid. `li`must be children (and the only direct children) of a `ul`.

In fact there is no need to use divs at all.

```css
    #header,
    #footer {
      background-color: #115279;
      float: left;
      padding: 15px 0;
      min-width: 100%;
    }
    .wrap {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 960px;
    }
    #topnavlist li {
      font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
      color: #D9330F;
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .NavItem {
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="wrap">
    <nav id="topnav">
      <!-- This is the top nav bar-->
      <ul id="topnavlist">
        <li>
          <!-- Home logo-->
          <a href="index.html">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="TechNow Logo" height="70" width="auto" />
          </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="NavItem">UK News</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="NavItem">Smartphones</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="NavItem">Reviews</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```